# Does unit testing prove functionality?

Tags: unit-testing, functional-testing

I have a silo type subsystem that takes in message inputs, completes its function, and then gives message outputs.

Each individual functions are simple and seems pointless to unit test them (Passing data to the correct register. Minimal logic) As a whole though, the subsystem is quite complex and it would be hard and time consuming to determine inputs and outputs. Where do you draw the line on how much to test and which way? Bottom up? or Top down?

Since the subsystem is self contained, can you prove that the subsystem works as a whole if you can prove each individual function on the unit test level?

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests are for testing each individual sub system. You have to write an integration test to ensure that all the different subsystems work in concert. You can not conclude that a program works just because the unit tests for its parts are passing. Mostly because unit tests typically abstract and simulate the integration points. You need the integration test to ensure proper integration between the different components.

I think it's a judgement call to decide what needs testing. 
No two system are equal, and the testing requirements are also often different for different systems

Comment: Your point makes sense, but just to clarify, each subsystem has individual functions that are unit tested. The subsystem works as a whole with other subsystems. I want to prove that each subsystem works on its own, but all the functions within it work correctly. Together or individually. 

Like I said, I still understand your point.

Do you have any references?

Comment: Sorry, no references. These are just my opinions, and each project will be different when it comes to how many tests you really need. 100% test coverage is typically not realistic, so my guiding principle is to add tests where ever they add value. Another point though is that even though everything works right now, adding extra tests will provide a security net if you ever refactor your code